# How to add a project built with node to GitHub

Tags: node.js, git, github

I recently built a project using node and express that makes use of a few NPMs, when I tried uploading the project to my GitHub repo I got an error message stating there were too many files, I'm guessing these were all the npm files in the node_modules folder. When I try to upload the project without including the npm files the project won't work, how can I get a functioning node project onto GitHub if it's too big?

Comment: what do you mean by the project won't work? where are you trying to run it. can you specify that.

Answer (score 1):

You really want a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.

Specifically, ignore `node_modules/`.

Try this one: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore

Comment: I created a gitignore file and added the node modules to it but without them the app won't even launch, the project uses Express, Axios and EJS without them it won't run.

Comment: @Nootuff Correct - you need to run `npm i` (or `yarn`) after cloning the repository. Standard practice is to _not_ commit node_modules and to npm install during deployment. If you want to be sure you have the same versions of dependencies you should commit the generated package-lock.json and use `npm ci` (slightly different for yarn).

Answer (score 0):

the node-modules folder need to be in the .gitignor file

Answer (score 0):

Add node_modules in your .gitignore file.
When you deploy your application run npm i so that node_modules are regenerated and your application will run as expected.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, would I have to write code into my app.js file to do that?

Comment: your node_modules will be saved in your package.json. try removing the node_module folder manually and type npm I in your root project, node_modules will be created automatically.